# How can I access another user's resources (specifically emails) using Microsoft Graph in an MVC app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I seem to be having issues giving my application the permissions required to access another user in the oranization's email messages. I had my admin grant my application all of the possible permissions through the Azure Portal and I’m getting an ‘Access is Denied’ error in the test application I downloaded from the Graph website. This makes me think that perhaps I am not using the correct call to the API.

Here is the code I’m using to retrieve another user’s email:

```
IMailFolderMessagesCollectionPage messages = await graphClient.Users["userID"].MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request().Top(25).GetAsync();
```

where “userID” is the id value I obtained from getting all users in my organization through the graph explorer.

Full code:

(Controller)

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetEmails()
        {
        try
        {
            // Initialize the GraphServiceClient.
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = SDKHelper.GetAuthenticatedClient();

            ResultsViewModel results = new ResultsViewModel();
            // Get the messages. 
            results.Items = await graphService.GetMyInboxMessages(graphClient);
            return View("Graph", results);
        }
        catch (ServiceException se)
        {
            if (se.Error.Code == Resource.Error_AuthChallengeNeeded) return new EmptyResult();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error", new { message = Resource.Error_Message + Request.RawUrl + ": " + se.Error.Message });
        }
    }
```

(graphService.cs)

```
public async Task<List<ResultsItem>> GetMyInboxMessages(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
    {
        List<ResultsItem> items = new List<ResultsItem>();

        // Get messages in the Inbox folder. 
        //IMailFolderMessagesCollectionPage messages = await graphClient.Me.MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request().GetAsync();  
        IMailFolderMessagesCollectionPage messages = await graphClient.Users["e87151ce-093b-4820-a98c-4cef247ed2be"].MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request().Top(25).GetAsync();

        string recipients = string.Empty;
        if (messages?.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Message message in messages)
            {
                //foreach (Recipient recipient in message.ToRecipients)                    
                for (int i = 0; i < message.ToRecipients.Count(); i++)
                    recipients += ((i != 0 ? "; " : "") + message.ToRecipients.ElementAt(i).EmailAddress.Address.ToString());

                items.Add(new ResultsItem
                {
                    Type = "message",
                    SentDateTime = message.SentDateTime.Value.DateTime.ToLocalTime(),
                    Subject = message.Subject,
                    From = message.From.EmailAddress.Address.ToString(),
                    To = recipients,
                    Id = message.Id,
                    Body = message.Body.Content.ToString()
                });
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
```

Is this an incorrect GET request? Or is it a permissions issue?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you share the claims inside your token? You can use a [site like this](http://jwt.calebb.net/) to decode your token.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could request app only token (client credential flow) using `Read mail in all mailboxes` application permissions for access to the Microsoft Graph.  According to your description , you register application in azure portal (azure ad v1.0) , you could try below steps:

1. set `Read mail in all mailboxes` application permissions for microsoft graph api :
   [image]
2. ask your admin to grant permissions (do admin consent for application permission)for all accounts in current directory by clicking `Grant Permissions` button as shown in above screenshot .
3. Use client credential flow to acquire app only token using ADAL library :
   AzureAuthenticationProvider .cs :

   ```
   public class AzureAuthenticationProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
   {
       private string _azureDomain = "xxxx.onmicrosoft.com";

       public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
       {
         try
         {
           string clientId = "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx";
           string clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

           AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + _azureDomain + "/oauth2/token");

           ClientCredential credentials = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

           AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", credentials);

           request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authResult.AccessToken);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
         }
       }
   }
   ```

   if you decode your token , you will find `Mail.Read` app permission in `roles` claim .
4. Then you could use Microsoft graph client library to get mails of users :

   ```
       GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new AzureAuthenticationProvider());

       //List<ResultsItem> items = new List<ResultsItem>();           
       IMailFolderMessagesCollectionPage messages = await graphClient.Users["77cac441-8279-452e-8904-ff24ddf5c715"].MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request().Top(25).GetAsync();
   ```
5. The result :
   [image]

Comment: The key I was missing was `Users[<User Id Here>]` and the fact that you can keep doing that for `Users['<User Id Here>].Messages[<Message Id Here>]`, etc...I really wish they gave this example in the SDK documentation. Thanks!